# SSIS 2008: SQL Server Data Source fails to authenticate in package even though the test connection is successful

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, etl

I am running a package that has a SQL Server Database as a Data Source. When I click on the DataSource in the Connection Managers window and click on Test Connection it connects just fine. [image]

However when I run the package, the step where I am writing to the database that uses this Data Source gets upset and returns the following error:

```
SSIS package "ImportModerators.dtsx" starting.
Information: 0x4004300A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Error: 0xC0202009 at ImportModerators, Connection manager "StagingDatabase": SSIS Error      Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"    Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user 'asrm'.".
Error: 0xC020801C at Data Flow Task, Add new Moderators [422]: SSIS Error Code  DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to  the connection manager "StagingDatabase" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be  error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method  call failed.
Error: 0xC0047017 at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: component "Add new Moderators" (422) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
Error: 0xC004700C at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
SSIS package "ImportModerators.dtsx" finished: Failure.
```

Why would the test connection work but then say that the login failed for the database user when I run the package?

Here is a configuration we are using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTSConfiguration><DTSConfigurationHeading><DTSConfigurationFileInfo GeneratedBy="xxxxxx" GeneratedFromPackageName="CleanData" GeneratedFromPackageID="{53268653-3492-4431-A92B-6A7A179AECC6}" GeneratedDate="8/1/2014 2:25:49 PM"/>        </DTSConfigurationHeading>
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property"  Path="\Package.Connections[StagingDatabase].Properties[ConnectionString]"  ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxxxx\SQLEXPRESS2008;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxxxxxxx;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Persist Security Info=True;Auto Translate=False;Application Name=SSIS-Package1-{A9C89B7E-189F-4EF8-A690-61331A45D70D}localhost.xxxxxx;</ConfiguredValue>
</Configuration>
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Connections[StagingDatabase].Properties[Password]" ValueType="String">
    <ConfiguredValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</ConfiguredValue>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: From the small image, all I can see is the "login failed for user.... " error. Any configuration overwriting the connection string?

Comment: made the error easier to read. There is a configuration file being used but as far as I can tell the credentials in it are correct to connect to the database...I'll add the config file to the question for more context

Comment: +1 for adding great details. Please go ahead and disable the configurations for the sake of testing. Once you do that, test the package once again and see if the credentials still work. If they do, then you have a problem with the configuration. If they dont, you have a problem with the credentials themselves.

Comment: Regarding the configuration file, what I find strange is that I have multiple packages in the same solution that are all writing to this same database using this Data Source . This package is the only one that for some reason freaks out. Also, if I go use SQL Management Studio to connect to the database in question using the credentials in the configuration file it totally works. So I don't think it's an issue of the credentials being wrong. This is really weird!

Comment: Then my guess would be an expression somewhere on the connection string thats messing up the whole thing. Can you also set the DelayValidation = True for this package and see if the helps.

Comment: I set DelayValidation to be true on the package as well as the Data Flow tasks that contains the task where I write to the DB but no luck--still getting the same error. It's just so weird that it works for all my other packages except this one!